# application of the theorem of the open application

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $ X, Y $ be Banach spaces.

Suppose that $ T: X \to Y $ is a compact operator. show that if $ \dim Y $ is infinite, then $ T $ is not surjective.

idea: Using the theorem of the open application

Comment: Try applying the open mapping [not "application" in English] theorem to the unit ball of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B_X$ (resp. $B_Y$) be the open unit ball of $X$ (resp. $Y$), and $\overline{B_X}$ (resp. $\overline{B_Y}$) its closure, the closed unit ball.

Assume $T$ is surjective and bounded. By the [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29), $T$ is open whence, in particular, $T(B_X)$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $Y$. So $T(B_X)$ contains $rB_Y$ (the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $0$) for some $r>0$. Then
$$
rB_Y\subseteq T(B_X)\; \Rightarrow \; r\,\overline{B_Y}=\overline{rB_Y}\subseteq \overline{T(B_X)}\subseteq T(\overline{B_X})\; \Rightarrow\; \overline{B_Y}\subseteq r^{-1}T(\overline{B_X}).
$$
Now if $T$ is compact, it means that $T(\overline{B_X})$ is relatively compact (compact, actually, in this case, but that's not needed). It follows that $\overline{B_Y}$ is compact, as a closed subset of the (relatively) compact set $r^{-1}T(\overline{B_X})$.

Hence $Y$ is finite-dimensional by (the application of) [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma): a normed vector space is finite-dimensional if and only its closed unit ball is norm compact.

Comment: It is probably because my English is weak, but: what means "its close unit ball is norm compact". That sentence is confusing for me. (I know that finite-dimensional normed space $\iff$ locally compact space (every closed and bounded subset is compact))

Comment: @Cortizol It means the closed unit ball is compact in the norm topology. There are other (interesting) topologies on infinite dimensional vector spaces, and sometimes, the closed unit ball (with respect to the norm) is compact in some of these topologies. Also, locally compact is different from "every closed and bounded subset is compact", the latter property is one that many interesting infinite-dimensional spaces have (spaces of holomorphic functions on open sets, for example). Of course, these spaces are not normable.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I forgot to write **normed** space is locally compact, etc. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Cortizol Actually, finite-dimensional $\iff$ locally compact holds for all (Hausdorff) topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. But locally compact means $\bigl(\exists U\bigr)(U \text{ is a neighbourhood of } 0 \land U \text{ is compact})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer In my book it says: **Def.** Normed space $X$ it's called locally compact if it every bounded closed set in $X$ is compact. And we work with vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. In other words: we are beginners and we works with metric spaces and nice vector spaces :-) So "my" definition of locally compactness is not probably good enough, but it's is good enough for our needs (oh, that my splendid English...)

Comment: @Cortizol I don't like that definition very much, but as a characterisation of **normed** [resp. _normable_] locally compact spaces, it works. Because a space is normable iff it is locally convex and locally bounded. Locally bounded means it has a bounded neighbourhood of $0$. Thus take the closure of a bounded neighbourhood of $0$, and you have a closed and bounded - hence compact - neighbourhood of $0$. My point is, not all topological vector spaces are normable. No infinite dimensional TVS is locally compact, normable or not. But there are infinite-dimensional TVS with the...

Comment: ...Montel property (or, if you prefer, the Heine-Borel[-Lebesgue] property), that every closed and bounded subset is compact. As I said above, these spaces are of course not normable (they are not locally bounded).

Comment: @DanielFischer " space is normable iff it is locally convex and locally bounded", I didn't know that information, thanks for that. Just to mention that "my" book is written for bachelor studies (I hope I got it) and it's pretty nice book (I really like it). Thanks for all explanation! :-)

Comment: @Cortizol Wow, a lot is going on here. I have nothing to add to Daniel Fischer's comments. He answered your questions better than I would have done. Just an example: the closed unit ball of a dual space is always weak* compact (Banach-Alaoglu). Hence the closed unit ball is always weakly compact in a reflexive space. So it is always good to mention what topology you have in mind.